# Gateway doesn't change when connecting to openVPN on 1 specific client

Tags: vpn, ip, openvpn, gateway

I set up an openVPN server on my ASUS RT-68U router. The [settings on the router are here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnYax.png) The .ovpn file generated by the router looks like [this](https://pastebin.com/MCBsBsqG). I can connect succesfully on all clients. However, on one client, the public IP doesn't change. I have looked at the routing table and saw that the gateway through which it connects to the server IP is not the same gateway as on the server. The client does not have access to settings on their router. I made sure that this client starts openVPN in administrator mode, but it doesn't help. What could be the problem? I don't suspect it's server side, since it does work for other clients.

Please keep in mind that I am a beginner in all this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, your client config files need to include `redirect-gateway def1` if you want to route all traffic through the VPN.

Once you do that, though, you'll need to ensure that your router is configured to perform outbound NAT for clients in the OpenVPN subnet.

Comment: Hi, 

Thanks for your response. I have added `redirect-gateway def1` to the client config file. The client is not able to connect anymore. Did I do something wrong? Also, how do I ensure that the router is configured to perform outbound NAT for clients in the OpenVPN subnet?